# Adding /repository-name/ to base in vite.config.ts file causes errors in github pages and pictures won't load

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, vite

As the name suggests, when I deploy my react vite site in Github pages with base: "/repository-name/" to vite.config.ts the website goes blank. The console also throws this error:

[image: error from adding base]

When I comment the code out the site runs with no errors, but I have another issue which is that images wont load in  tags or as background. I made sure the path to the sources are correct, double checked the spelling and capitalization in my file and inside the repo. The folders' names stayed the same, and I tried adding ./ instead of / and also omitting the beginning /.

Other repos that I have checked that deployed on Github pages used the base variable in the vite config file and I assume that's what makes the loading of images possible but mines just throws an error.

Here is a screenshot of my file structure for the repo and also the different paths I tried.

[image: file structure]

All pictures are under the assets folder.

EDIT:
So I tried messing around with things and at the top I added

```
import tree from "../assets/tree.jpg";
```

and then added a `<img src={tree} />` and this works, but I don't get why it doesn't work when I use a string as the path directly in the img tag. If I have to do it this way then I will have a bunch of import statements at the top and I don't really think that is a great solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally figured it out. Webpack only packs images that you import
so it doesn't know that it should put the image at "../assets/image1.png" in the bundle unless you import it. That is why images weren't loading for me. If you don't want to import the assets Vite has another way to do it, which is to put your assets in the public directory inside your root directory.